# Dynamic content in Angular 4 not styled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using a masonry container and lightbox together to create a gallery page on my site.

```
<div id="macy-container" style="visibility:none;">
  <div *ngFor="let image of _albums; let i=index" [className]="'demo'">
     <img [src]="image.src" (click)="open(i)"  [className]="'demo-image'" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having an issue where if I hard code the images everything works great but as soon as I try to render dynamically the masonry doesn't render. If you try to inspect then the control will render. I've also tried doing a timeout function which will render the control correctly.

I'm realizing that this is basically a race issue. My image data is coming from a service:

```
getImageData(){
  return this.http.get("./assets/eat.json")
  .map((res:Response) => res.json().images); //records in this case
}
```

In the page where I want that data I'm calling the service in my constructor thusly:

```
import { AppService } from './../core/app.service';
import { EatModule } from './eat.module';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Lightbox } from 'angular2-lightbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-eat',
  templateUrl: './eat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eat.component.scss'],
  providers: [ AppService ]
})
export class EatComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  private _album: Array<string> = [];
  public _albums:Array<any> = [];
  private myJsonData : any;
constructor(private _lightbox: Lightbox,private http: Http, private appService: AppService) {

  this.appService.getImageData().subscribe((data) => {

    console.log("JSON data is - ", data);
    this.myJsonData = data;

    for(let result of this.myJsonData){
      const album = { 
        src : result.src,
        caption : result.caption,
        thumb : result.thumb
      }
          this._albums.push(album);
    }
  });

}
```

Then in my ngOnInit I load my styles for my masonry:

```
ngOnInit() {

 var masonry = new Macy({
container: '#macy-container',
trueOrder: false,
waitForImages: true,
debug: true,
margin: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
}
 })
}
```

There aren't any errors and the page renders but doesn't apply the styles to the masonry container. If you inspect the page then the styles magically appear and the page renders correctly.

Comment: sounds like a change detection issue. whatever library you're using isn't integrated with angular 2 correctly

Comment: That's what I figured. If I put a timeout function on my style loading in my ngOninit for 2 seconds then it works just fine. I was just trying to figure out when the best time to load the json and the styles is.

Comment: probably try it afterViewInit... but I'd say you probably don't want to use a poorly integrated 3rd party lib

Comment: I'd love to use a fully integrated library but sometimes you have to integrate things that are not. My goal here is to figure out the best way to include non integrated libraries seamlessly.

Comment: you can try use ngAfterContentInit()

Comment: As a general comment, you should ALWAYS be wrapping 3rd party libraries in your own components or directives, no matter how well integrated they are, as a matter of best practice to reduce your exposure to them.  And I strongly disagree that you sometimes need to use things that aren't properly integrated.  I've built several enterprise angular applications and have not yet needed to use a poor 3rd party library.  Because I immediately exclude any library that isn't well built for the task at hand.  Otherwise you're trading a quick search for a better lib for countless headaches down the line.